# Access the UIPanGestureRecognizer driving tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using the new iOS 11 `tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` methods to add swipey actions to my table cell rows.  I need some additional animations tied to that pan gesture.  How can I access the gesture recognizer that I am assuming is driving those methods?

Here's some relevant code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    //
    // I WANT TO DO SOME ANIMATION STUFF WITH THE PAN GESTURE RECOGNIZER HERE
    //

    let item = coreData.listResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Quantity", handler: { (action, view, completionHandler) in
        print("Show count now")
    })
    let sortOrder = item.category?.sortOrder ?? 0
    action.backgroundColor = UIColor.OMGColors.section[sortOrder]
    action.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)).image { _ in
        guard let image = UIImage(named:"Pound Sign") else {
            return
        }
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))

    }
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    return configuration

}
```

Is it possible to access the pan gesture recognizer at all here, or do I need to stop using `tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` and roll my own so I have access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access them, but unfortunately I'm not sure it'll help you much.

You'll find them in the `gestureRecognizers` property of your tableview, like any other gesture recognizer.

However, it's a custom subclass of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which seems to be private API:

```
_UISwipeActionPanGestureRecognizer
```

You can cast to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but it might not be advisable to try since that class is undocumented private API; these things are liable to change without any warning between iOS versions, and Apple don't like you doing that kind of thing anyway.

Comment: Thanks Pete.  I ended up adding a new panGestureRecognizer to the table cell itself and then using the delegate method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` to allow it to live peacefully alongisde the built-in ones generated by `tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)`.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @BrianM that’s a good solution, thanks for the update, I’ll remember that in case I come across the same problem in future.